# How to declare regex for inheritance(class childclass : baseclass) type?

Tags: c#, regex

How to declare inheritance format in regex?

I have tried all the cases specified below but it Regex.IsMatch always returns false

```
class \w\W+[:\s\w,]+
class \w+[\s?][\s:[\s?]\w,]+
class \w\s+[\s:\s\w]
```

I need to set the regex for inheritance(class childclass : baseclass) and the format should return true(Regex.IsMatch),it returns false for the following test case:

public class childclass : baseclass

Comment: Consider that it would be hard to determine(if even it is possible) that the right side of ':' character is a class or an interface.

Comment: If you want to get exact results (the same as the compiler "sees"), you could use `Roslyn` because with this, you have access to the compiler itself, but this might be a bit too complicated, depending on your usecase.

Comment: It return true when regex is set as class \w+[\s:\w] but in this case class is not considered as a keyword.

Comment: In general case, you want a *parser*, it's very difficult for regex to match, say, `myClass : /* comment */ baseClass`, `class myClass : // /* broken comment\r\n : baseClass // ...*/ ` and not match `@"string - class myClass : baseClass"`

Comment: I think those regexes are not doing anything like what you think they are. You cannot nest character classes, and [?] matches a literal ? which is certainly not what you want. A regex for your test case is `class\s+\w+\s*:\s*\w+`

Comment: Do you need to handle cases like: `class MyClass : global::MyNamespace.MyBaseClass` or `class A<T> : B where T : class`?

Comment: only class childclass : baseclass

Answer (score 0):

Please try [this](https://regexr.com/4bmpm)  regex

(public|private|internal|protected)*(partial)*\s*class\s+(/*.**/)*\s*\w+[\s]*\s+(/*.**/)*\s*:\s+(/*.**/)*\s*\s*(\w+,*\w+)

Comment: No Regex.IsMatch is returned as false.

Comment: This makes too many assumptions: e.g. public/private is not required, what about internal, you can use as many spaces before and after the colon as you want and so on...

Comment: please have a look on the link i think it is working

Comment: @Mahmoud-Abdelslam: Better but still many issues: e.g. `partial` keyword, or, what is, if the user types any comment between the class and the base class, which is also syntactically legal

Comment: @FlatEric ok i will match this

Comment: @Mahmoud-Abdelslam: Not working for multiline comments (one or more CRLF between `/*` and `*/` or for multiple comments like `/*comment 1*/ // comment2`. What I want to say: **It is very hard to think of all possible combinations**

Comment: @FlatEric i agree with u that  it is complicated ,we can do this modification but i don't think it is very common to use multi-line comment between class and the implemented interface ,it all depends on what he is trying to match

Comment: That's true, but a much more common case is also not working: Generics!

Comment: Yes it may not satisfy all test cases

Comment: @HariHBK do u need to satisfy all the language specifications for defining a class ?

Answer (score 0):

Example of a simple pattern that fulfills your criteria: `\w+ class \w+ : \w+` (one word, class keyword, class name, colon, base class name).

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var input = @"
using System;

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
}
";
        var pattern = @"\w+ class \w+ : \w+";
        var isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern);
        var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

        Console.WriteLine(isMatch);
        Console.WriteLine(matches.Count);
        Console.WriteLine(matches[0]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
True
1
public class ChildClass : BaseClass
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/K9RNbJ